# Avoid sorting in groupBy lodash method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, group-by, lodash

I'm working on an array which needs to be grouped, but original order to be maintained. So I tried alternate solutions but still that is not maintaining original array order. Resulting Order should be according to the 'year' in original array. Below is the array and its solution with result and expected object

```
  const cars = [
      {
          'make': 'ford',
          'model': 'fusion',
          'year': '2015'
      },
      {
          'make': 'audi',
          'model': 'r8',
          'year': '2012'
      },
{
          'make': 'ford',
          'model': 'fusion',
          'year': '2015'
      },    
{
      'make': 'honda',
      'model': 'city',
      'year': '2012'
  },
       {
          'make': 'audi',
          'model': 'rs5',
          'year': '2013'
      },
      {
          'make': 'ford',
          'model': 'mustang',
          'year': '2012'
      },
    ];

function groupBy(data, property) {
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
const reGroup = (list, key) => {
    const newGroup = {};
    list.forEach(item => {
        const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        newGroup[item[key]] = newGroup[item[key]] || [];
        newGroup[item[key]].push(newItem);
    });
    return newGroup;
};

console.log(reGroup(cars, 'year'));
console.log(groupBy(cars, 'year'));

output -
 {
  '2012': [
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'honda', model: 'city', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }
  ],
  '2013': [ { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
  '2015': [
    { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
    { make: 'honda', model: 'city', year: '2015' }
  ]
}

expected- 
   {
     '2015': [
        { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
        { make: 'honda', model: 'city', year: '2015' }
      ]
      '2012': [
        { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
        { make: 'honda', model: 'city', year: '2012' },
        { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }
      ],
      '2013': [ { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
    }
```

Comment: Output is same as the expected because both are the same object with the same properties and their respective array values are identical

Comment: check the "year' is different order

Comment: The order of object properties in ES6 follows [these rules](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

Comment: You cannot "sort" the year properties: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219) Keys that are non-negative integers will show up in ascending order.

Comment: Do not understand what is the order you want: `2012, 20113, 2015`?

Comment: 2015, 2012, 2013 is the order I wanted

Comment: Understood. I think you should work with array to keep the order.. I have voted to reopen to share my solution